# Can't change font size of a href

Tags: html, css

I want to change the font size of my a href that links back to the top of the page.

My html code:

```
<a href="#topofpage" class="top">Return to top of page</a>
```

My css code:

```
a.top (
font-size:40px;
}
```

Comment: Is the typo only here in `a.typo(` (instead of `a.typo{`) or in your original code also? If that typo is corrected, the `font-size` should work fine unless there is any over-riding setting elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Your css error try

```
a.top {
font-size:40px;
}
```

Comment: So hard to tell the difference between parenthesis and curly brackets on my text editor. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix here: you used a parenthesis (`(`) instead of a curly brace (`{`).

```
a.top {
    font-size:40px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/8kXKm/)